# Loop thru controls on another workbooks userform

Tags: excel, vba

OK I have searched and searched on how to do this properly. Here goes. I have 2 workbooks. In the first workbook I have some userforms (nested userforms that create a user interface for data input that is then saved to worksheets). Each userform of course has controls. The 2nd workbook has the macros. I have a read and write macro in this workbook that is invoked at appropriate times for reading and writing. In some cases, I have special write scenarios that require a little more processing. I have been able to use the application.run approach to run the macros in the 2nd workbook from the 1st workbook userforms.

Here's where I'm stomped. The times where I have to special write scenarios, in order to do this, while in the 2nd workbook's macros, I need to refer back to the 1st workbook launch an alternative userform and then loop thru the controls (textboxes) and update certain textbox values. To attempt this, I was performing 'Application.Run ("'" & wb.Name & "'!showNA")' which will open and initialize the other userform in the 1st workbook. Then I want to loop thru it's controls using 'For Each ctrl In vbcompfrm.Designer.Controls' of which I can not get to work and have tried many different syntax and combinations. Help! I do have the extensibility reference checked in tools as well. I am a self taught vba hobbyist so please go easy on my approach :D Thank you so much.

```
    'code in workbook 2'
Public Sub test(ByRef FRM)
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
Dim vbcompfrm As VBComponent
Dim SubStr As String
Dim MyArr() As Variant
Dim key As String
Dim ATTR As String

ReDim MyArr(1)
MyArr(0) = "first"
MyArr(1) = "second"

Set ws = wb.Worksheets("testws")
    Application.Run ("'" & wb.Name & "'!showNA")    'this will show the userform NA form the first workbook'
    'Application.Run ("'" & wb.Name & "'!hideNA")
    With UserForms("tbls_RTU_NA")
        Set vbcompfrm = wb.VBProject.VBComponents("NA")    'this is the userform in the first workbook, we want to loop thru the controls'
        For Each ctrl In vbcompfrm.Designer.Controls    'not sure how to make this work'
            With ctrl
                For i = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
                    If .ControlTipText = MyArr(i) Then
                        datasplit = Split(MyArr(i), "_")
                        key = datasplit(0)
                        ATTR = datasplit(1)
                        .Text = SearchDataArray(StandardTableDataArray, "NA_" & key, ATTR)    'don't forget we need to set the value of the new text to the array value once we match the key
                    End If
                Next i
            End With
        Next ctrl
    End With
```

Comment: First question would be why separate these items across two workbooks? - just makes life more difficult and running code using `Application.Run` is a pain.

Comment: because i have 15+ workbooks that use the same code that i'm iteritavely updating and finding bugs, so fixing and updating all workbooks is a pain. So, i traded the that pain for the pain of using application.run in hopes that once i get finished with the setup, no more pain. :D I did think about doing a main macro workbook and just copying in the newest macros each time one of the 15 are ran. Suggestions? or help on the above approach?

Comment: You don't have to have all the macros and forms in multiple workbooks, but you can combine the macros and forms in a single workbook, and have them operate on whichever workbook you need to run them for.